# How to disable "JavaScript feeds" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript, feed

How do you disable "JavaScript feeds" in Firefox for a certain site and not disable JavaScript totally?

Comment: Can you comment with an example site?

Comment: www.tyda.se the little text that is appearing in the top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the NoScript plugin. It allows fine-grained control over the sites that you want to have scripts run from.

- Homepage: http://noscript.net/
- Plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/722

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer: [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722)